# Python: If header exists, use as variable

Tags: python

I am working with a HDUList with many columns (over 1000). The columns are related to characteristics of galaxies in clusters fit by an external code. The columns should end in 'ser' or 'dev'. However, some columns are too long and the names get cut off (eg: LOGRE_F3mF2_F850LPse or eLOGRE_F3mF2_F850LPs)

I am defining functions to do various operations with the data. I am having a hard time systematically select the columns I want because the name are all different.

Current procedure (part relevant to question):

```
def function(xaxisroot,yaxisroot,otheroptions):
  xaxis = xaxisroot + '_avg_f850lpser' 
  yaxis = yaxisroot + '_F' + str(region[0]) + 'mF' + str(region[1]) + '_f850lpser'

function('logre','logre')
```

Since the column is actually: 'LOGRE_avg_F850LPse'
I get the error (example):

```
KeyError: "Key 'logre_avg_f850lpser' does not exist."
```

Comment: If the column is 'LOGRE_F3mF2_F850LPse' why do you do xaxis = xaxisroot + '_avg_f850lpser'  ? Surely you're using this variable somewhere which is returning the error?

Comment: The 'xaxisroot' is LOGRE. There's columns for their average value, and the value in different fields. (F3mF2). I just put the wrong line. The problem is when creating the column names, I think there was a character limit (I don't know because that part wasn't my job)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like names are cutoff at 20 characters. If that's the case, you can try something along the lines of:

```
key = root + '_avg_f850lpser' 
key = key[:20]
```

That ensures your `key` is always 20 characters or less, and trimmed at the right end of the string (since that where the cut-off appears to happen).

If the 20 characters is not where the cut-off (always) happens, you'll need to show more examples of cut-off column keys.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `hasattr(object,property)` to detect if the key actually exists. Otherwise try restructuring your dictionaries so that you don't have weird names like that.

Comment: I thought of something like that, but I would have to have so many loops.